# Is there a way to pull out the Foundation type from Network.Wai.Application in Yesod?

Tags: haskell, yesod

Given that `makeApplication` returns already converted `Network.Wai.Application` and most of the API seems to be using that, is there a way to pull out the foundation type from it?

For example if I have `getApplicationDev` somewhere, but I'd like to access some of the data stored in my `App` record (the foundation type.)

The only alternative seems to be to abandon the helpers that return `Wai.Application` and re-build it myself whenever I need it, but that seems a bit redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no way to do that. You'd need to modify `makeApplication` to return both an `Application` and an `App` value.